# How can I read out of a MySQL database in xcode/swift

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, macos, swift

I was wondering how could I read data out of my MySQL database into `swift/xcode`.

I searched all over the internet and i just need to know how to read out of a database that on my `webhost`. I do understand how `PHP` works, but I do not know everything about `xcode`.

If something isn't clear, feel free to ask.

Regards,

Jenoah

Comment: What have you tried so far? As you say you know how PHP works, then presumably you would be looking for some way to make a request. Try Google / search stack overflow using some of these keywords: Swift, PHP, Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand your problem. You can not execute `MySQL` queries directly from `xcode`. For that you need to have `web-services`.

You can create web-services in `PHP` or any other languages. Pass parameters in your URL (GET or POST). and use those params to deal with your database. Finally, output it in either `json` or `xml`.

Now, from xcode side you need to call that URL and fetch response from your json or xml.

There are bunch of libraries out there by which you can call web-services from xcode. I am not into `ios` programming so, I don't know that much about it. But, you have to create those services by your own. Hope this will help you.

Comment: You can link the C mysql client provided by MySQL into your app and call mysql functions directly. Here is an example; https://github.com/thrivesmart/just-mysql-example-mac-app-objective-c-xcode

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to post some parts of your code because your question is not specific.

With that information, I can only tell you that you have to connect your Swift code to a PHP file (using POST) and then in that .php file connect to the database. If you want to read the results from that database, you can use JSON to read the information.

If you show us your code we could helo you better.

Thanks,